# How to make login viewmodel with mutable state

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**My LoginRepository**

```
interface LoginRepository {

    suspend fun postLogin(
        loginRequest: LoginRequest
    ): Resource<Login>
}
```

**My LoginRepoImpl**

```
@Singleton
class LoginRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api:ApiClient,
):LoginRepository{
    override suspend fun postLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Resource<Login> {
        return try {
            val result = api.login(loginRequest)
            Resource.Success(result.toLoginDomain())
        }catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            Resource.Error("Could not load login")
        }catch (e:HttpException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            Resource.Error("Internet connection problem")
        }
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf<LoginState>(LoginState.InProgress)
    val state: State<LoginState> get() = _state

    fun login(username: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val login = async { useCase.execute(loginRequest = LoginRequest(username,password)) }
        _state = _state.value
    }
```

Please help me, i have no idea, sorry i just startd my career as android developer 1 month ago. so i am new in android development.

Comment: Share also your LoginUseCase

Comment: '
class LoginUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LoginRepository
) {

    suspend fun execute(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Resource<Login> {
        return repository.postLogin(loginRequest)
    }
}'

Comment: @MaratZangiev is it correct for the usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a small improvement in your viewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf<LoginState>(LoginState.InProgress)
    val state: State<LoginState> get() = _state

    fun login(username: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val loginDeferred = async { useCase.execute(loginRequest = LoginRequest(username,password)) }
        when (loginDeferred.await()) {
           is Resource.Success -> _state.value = LoginState.Success
           is Resource.Error -> _state.value = LoginState.Error
        }
    }
}
```

What have we done there? We are waiting to login result via `await` operator. After that we push new `LoginState` depending on result.

Comment: so ,  should i make login state ? how and which i should put in login state. and what the functionality for it ?

Comment: You already have login state in your code (`LoginState.InProgress`). I just expand your code by `LoginState.Success` and `LoginState.Error`.
What functionality you should put to it depends on you and what do you want.
For example: 
LoadingState.InProgress -> show progress bar;

LoadingState.Error -> show error;

LoadingState.Success -> save user data and open the app main flow;