# Why i'm getting logged out everytime I re-open app in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

MainActivity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val userDataControl: UserDataControl by viewModels()
    private var mAuthListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        mAuthListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            if (user != null) {
                // User is logged in
                userDataControl.updateLoginStatus(true)
            } else {
                // User is not logged in
                userDataControl.updateLoginStatus(false)
            }
        }

        // Add the AuthStateListener when the activity is created
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener!!)

        setContent {
            MelonFeedTheme {
                val scaffoldHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
                val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                Scaffold(
                    snackbarHost = {
                        SnackbarHost(hostState = scaffoldHostState) {
                            Snackbar(
                                snackbarData = it
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    content = { padding ->
                        // Use the state from your ViewModel or some other mechanism to decide the start destination
                        NavigationHost(
                            userDataControl = userDataControl,
                            startDestination = if (userDataControl.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                                Screens.HomeScreen.route
                            } else {
                                Screens.RegisterNest.route
                            },
                            navController,
                            scaffoldHostState,
                            coroutineScope
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Add the AuthStateListener when the activity starts or resumes
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener!!)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        // Remove the AuthStateListener when the activity is stopped
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener!!)
        }
    }
}
```

UserDataControl ViewModel:

```kotlin
class UserDataControl : ViewModel() {

    private val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val usersRef: DatabaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users")
    private val passwordPattern =
        Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,16}$")

    private val usernamePattern =
        Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\$")

    private var isUserLoggedIn: Boolean = false

    fun setUserLoggedIn(loggedIn: Boolean) {
        isUserLoggedIn = loggedIn
    }

    fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return isUserLoggedIn
    }


    fun updateLoginStatus(isLoggedIn: Boolean) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            setUserLoggedIn(isLoggedIn)
        }
    }


    // other code
}
```

Now in MainActivity I'm trying to check if user is logged in or not and taking them to respective screens. Now let's say I logged in to the app and then re-opened it, now what I want is to go to the HomeScreen but it takes me to LoginScreen(ResgisterNest).

And also please tell how can I use authStateListener in my project

I tried many thing but it didnt work. Please help
Its been 5 days trying

Comment: Check this example; https://stackoverflow.com/a/74931839/14162959 isUserLoggedIn must be a state for read of change by MainActivity.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **700** (seven hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). It's a working solution.

Comment: "how can I use authStateListener in my project" -> See https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android